# Datatables, if else inside options

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Is there a way i can enable/disable deferLoading inside the datatable options using javascript ? 
Based on some user selections i want to be able let the table show results on page refresh, or wait till the user selects something from a filter.

Lets say i have this datatable.

```
function initTestTable(){
    myTable =  $('#testTable').DataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "request.php?action=list",
    ......
 });
}
```

What i want to do is something like this: (i know its wrong)

```
    //so basically if dontShow is 1 then the datatable wont show anything
    var dontShow = 1;

    function initTestTable(){
        myTable =  $('#testTable').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        if (dontShow === 1){
        "deferLoading": 0,
        }
        "sAjaxSource": "request.php?action=list",
        ......
     });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't let Datatable or jQuery confuse you, your problem is not with them. Your problem is just how to create an object with a set of keys depending on some condition.

This part of the question, to be clear:

```
{
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    if (dontShow === 1){
    "deferLoading": 0,
    }
    "sAjaxSource": "request.php?action=list",
    ......
 }
```

Now the we focused on the problem, I think it will be easier to solve. You just have to create an object that has a property depending on a condition. A very vanilla and simple solution would be:

```
data = {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "request.php?action=list",
    ......
}

if (dontShow === 1){
    data.deferLoading = 0
}
```

Then you just feed that `data` object to the Datatable constructor `$('#testTable').DataTable(data)` and you're done.